# How Can I Get Mitmproxy Docker to Work on Windows Bash?

Tags: windows, bash, docker, daemon, mitmproxy

When I try running `mitmproxy` Docker container on Windows `bash`, I get an error message that the Docker daemon isn't running. How can I get it to run?

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 mitmproxy/mitmproxy

docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things to get `mitmproxy` Docker container to work on Windows `bash`.

First, in bash: `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375`

Secondly, in Windows: check the box in Docker Settings->General->"Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS"

Now the following command will run correctly in bash.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 mitmproxy/mitmproxy
```